# Crystal Report With Multiple Conditions For Charts

Tags: sql, vb.net, charts, crystal-reports

I have a table that contains 2 columns like that

```
(OD) / (SV)

(2014-10-13) / (647423.00)

(2014-10-14) / (40272.72)

(2014-11-14) / (757531.50)

(2014-11-15) / (87175.44)

(2014-12-15) / (0.00)

(2014-13-16) / (126031.50)
```

I need to make a single report that contain all sales report for the last 3 months of 2014
In another way i want to Get 3 values like

- Total SV Where OD Between 2014-10-1 And 2014-10-30
- Total SV Where OD Between 2014-11-1 And 2014-11-30
- Total SV Where OD Between 2014-12-1 And 2014-12-30

and put all of this into a chart

my problem is that chart needs to take it's value from the database field directly or a report field

so how to make such a condition to allow the chart to have the 3 values in order to put it into chart?

PS : I'm using VB.NET in this

Comment: You say 3 columns, but only 2 are shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add 6 parameters to your report: `From1` `To1` `From2` `To2` `From3` `To3` (maybe it could be easier to put just one parameter `From` and then evaluate all others date using `Formula` fields)
2. Add a `grouping` field, based on the date and the periods chosen, so that values can be grouped and summarazed (this field can be created in the query)

   IF ({SalesRep1.OD}) >= {?From1} AND {SalesRep1.OD} <= {?To1}    THEN 1 ...
3. Create a `group` in the report (using Group Expert) and then a `Summarized Field` to evaluate totals on each group

Comment: Well, Thanks for your reply but i'm a little bit noob in Crystal Report so can you please explain in more details? Like how to add the grouping field as you mentions ..etc I would really appreciate more explanation

Comment: Well! i've tried step 1 and 2 on two months only but i face a problem in step 2
how i should make the formula for the grouping field??
i've made it like the
GroupName ({SalesRep1.OD}) IN {?From1} To {?To1} Or GroupName ({SalesRep1.OD}) In {?From2} To {?To2}
This situation showing month 10 and after all records it shows month 11
is the correct and if so how i proceed with step 3

Comment: From1 and To1 ar dates.. so IN and TO won't work, I suppose. You should use ({SalesRep1.OD}) >= {?From1} AND {SalesRep1.OD} <= {?To1}